# API poor performance

Tags: gunicorn

I have developed a REST API in Flask which will be deployed to production. The API basically gets a request with around 70 variables, writes a csv file, then calls (os.system(myCommand)) a R script which reads the csv file, do some math and returns a csv file with a result. Then the API reads the csv file with the final result and sends it back to the client. In order to test performance, I sent 60 requests simultaneously and the time is around 30s.

The API is running in a 10 virtual cores machine with 64Gb and SSD disk.

How many workers should be used? I got slightly better performance with 8 cores insted of 4, but any improvement using 10. What kind of workers should be used under that scenario? I tried both sync and async with no time difference.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.
Regards,
Àlex

Comment: how did you determine that gunicorn is the bottleneck?

Comment: Actually you're right. Not sure if gunicorn is the bottleneck. I was trying to find out if sync or async workers should have any impact under my scenario. When I comment the call to the R script, all 60 requests are fast., So I thought I/O could be affecting performance

Comment: I'd bet that all those csv read/write operations are expensive and suggest you test a memory storage solution instead. For example - use redis to pass data between your different services and take a look at rabbitmq for signals

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. Input csv file keeps 1 row with all 70 variables and output csv contains 1 row with a single value. All the process takes 1,2 seconds when called alone. Performance degrades when called 60 requests simultaneosly.